# CRC endianess transform

Tags: c, embedded, arm, crc

I'm working with an ARM cortex M3 board which has an hardware CRC calculation unit.
It supports 3 standard CRC polynominals. The interface to the module is very simple.
I need to provide a pointer to the data and the data length.
The problem I have is that it calculates LSB first.
and I need to know the CRC Msb first (xmodem crc16-itt).
Is there anyway to take the calculation it got and transform it into msb first?

Comment: When you say it calculates LSB first, you mean least significant bit or byte?  Is your problem with bit order or byte order?  I assume you are not saying just that the result contains the correct 2-byte CRC but just swapped order?

Comment: what cortex m3 board/chip is this?

Comment: the sam3s4 is what you said.  Now is this about speed or size?  Do you have to use the hardware crc engine or what if you had a small footprint software solution?

Comment: why is the data stored with the wrong endian?  is it transmitted or copied or shared in a way that cannot be swapped as received/sent?

Comment: @dwelch: When creating the firmware, you create a file on a PC which has different endianess than ARM. when the file is transferred to the device, it is saved in flash. because it's firmware I'm transferring, I can't switch the bytes around.

Comment: on the pc you could compute the crc using a different endian and not incur as much cost as on the arm.  is this a speed thing or size thing?  what about a small footprint software solution?  or a bigger footprint but faster software solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT/REWRITE:

From the information provided I think you have these choices:

1) arrange the data on the host (which is assumed to not be as resource constrained as a microcontroller) so that the microcontroller does not have to do as much work.

2) Make a (byteswapped) copy of the data using features/instructions where possible to make that faster, and then let the hardware CRC engine compute the crc.

3) Dont use the hardware crc engine, compute the crc using software.

4) Ignore the crc.

5) Use a different microcontroller (that can handle this use case).

Comment: It's Atmel sam3s4. and I looked at the datasheet, nothing mentioned regarding swapping endianess

Answer (score 0):

> [...] I need to know the CRC Msb first (xmodem crc16-itt).
>   Is there anyway to take the calculation it got and transform it into msb first?

The xmodem crc16-itt operates on **bytes** as data. So Most Significant Byte first or Least Significant Byte first will matter only for the *representation* of the CRC value. Just swap  the computed value - e.g. with `__REV16()` CMSIS function.

Edit:

I assumed both sides see `0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04` as such. If one side sees different bytes, e.g. `0x04 0x03 0x02 0x01` in memory then the CRC will fail. But you probably want to fix that sooner than later anyway, as that will give you severe headache when processing the data.

Comment: this does not work, both ends have to compute the same way to have the same results 0x6909 != 0xBB96 != C52D.  When rolling in the original crc, byteswapping does not result in a clean crc  0x6959 != 0x0000, etc.

Comment: crc is a serial computation that relies on the bit sequence, by changing the order of the bits around, do you expect to get the same result?  basically if I take 20 zeros and 20 ones should all combinations of serial sequences result in the same crc?

Comment: I said *byte* order, not *bit* order. *Byte* oder does not apply when working with single bytes. *Bit* order always matters, of course.

Comment: the hardware in question takes a chunk of memory and reads it in one order, the bytes were placed in the opposite order, so the bytes will be evaluated in a different order, the question is what to do about it without having to make a copy of the data with the bytes swapped (Before feeding the hardware).  So far I cant come up with a solution other than to not use the hardware.  using software it is pretty easy but is probably slower than the hardware solution, only testing will show it software is faster than swapping and using hardare

Comment: for example sender evaluates and sends the string "12345678", the other end evauluates "21436587" or "43218765" and the crc does not pass.  Now why the other end is receiving this data in this manner is a qood question, and maybe that is where the solution is.

Answer (score -1):

Just swap the 2 bytes like this:

```
unsigned short crc_little_endian = ...; // call to your CRC function
unsigned short crc_big_endian = (crc_little_endian >> 8) | (crc_little_endian << 8);
```

Comment: There more than two bytes, Its 128 bytes. and going over and reversing all of them is not efficient

Comment: Does the API support feeding the bytes one by one? If yes, feed them in reverse order. If not, then you'll need to reverse the order yourself. Alternatively, calculate it in software. There are plenty of fast algorithms around, especially those with a 256 byte table of pre-calculated values.

Comment: No, it doesn't. and the current imolementation is pre calculated. but you know embedded hardware, I need to save the space to something more importent, such as code...

Comment: this does not work, both ends have to compute the same way to have the same results 0x6909 != 0xBB96 != C52D.  When rolling in the original crc, byteswapping does not result in a clean crc  0x6959 != 0x0000, etc.